# Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path in my Spring MVC web application

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I got this error after making some changes to my `appconfig-security.xml` file

`appconfig-security.xml` 
`

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_INSTRUCTOR','ROLE_MEMBER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_INSTRUCTOR')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/profile" access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBER')"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.trygym.solution.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="encoder"
      class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
</beans:bean>
```

`

Before I had only one role in the database. Then I tried to do some security check and allocate access to users. Then I ended up with that error. I didn't make any changes to `web.xml`.

`web.xml`

`

```
<display-name>Gym Related Web Application</display-name>

<!-- Location of Java @Configuration classes that configure the components that makeup this application -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/appconfig-root.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

`

I am using spring hibernate. Please can anyone help me to find where it might be the error locate. Thanks.

`HomeController`

```
package com.trygym.solution.web;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


@Controller
class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "home";
}

}
```

`UserController`

```
package com.trygym.solution.web;

import com.trygym.solution.model.User;
import com.trygym.solution.service.SecurityService;
import com.trygym.solution.service.UserService;
import com.trygym.solution.validator.UserValidator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private SecurityService securityService;

@Autowired
private UserValidator userValidator;

@RequestMapping(value = "/forget_password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String forget_password(Model model) {
    //model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());

    return "forget_password";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String registration(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());

    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    userService.save(userForm);

    securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

    return "redirect:/welcome";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
    if (error != null)
        model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

    if (logout != null)
        model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(Model model) {
    return "welcome";
}
```

}

Comment: The changes you made to your security config and the exact message of the exception would help here

Comment: **HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/': {public java.lang.String com.trygym.solution.web.UserController.welcome(org.springframework.ui.Model), private java.lang.String com.trygym.solution.web.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)}**. This is the error I got and previously I had this in security config file `<intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>` and `<intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')`

Comment: Well from the error message it looks to me like you mapped these two methods(welcome and home) to path. I'm not quite sure how the security configuration would somehow affect this though

Comment: Then where should be the error? in the controller ? I'm bit new to hibernate

Comment: This has nothing to do with hibernate, but Spring. It seems that Spring finds one path being mapped to two different endpoints in a way that Spring doesn't know which method to actually call when the endpoint is accessed. In this case this seems to be the root path(`"/"`)

Comment: Please share your UserController. and HomeController.

Comment: I updated the question with adding those controller classes

Comment: There it is. You mapped welcome and home to the same path and request method. This is not supported. Do you really want welcome to be mapped to `/`? And if so, why.

Comment: Actually I think it's not necessary here. I'll make the change and right back

Comment: I did the change. But before that I restarted the server and I got another error when I try to submit login details to logging to the system saying **HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied**. I don't no what's going here

Comment: I added an answer for the original problem you posted. As for the 403 error: Looks like you don't have access to this endpoint. Maybe you have to manually provide an <intercept-url> element  and allow all access for this endpoint. Not sure, though, because I never really used XML configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that both `HomeController.home` and `UserController.welcome` are both mapped to `/` and Spring can't determine which method to call when the endpoint is accessed. Removing the mapping from one method resolves this particular issue.